# how to precompile, concat, minify, prefix, and zip scripts/stylesheets in expressjs?

Tags: express, gruntjs

I know I can use gruntjs but it seems it's suited for simple tasks and I can't figure out to embed more logic into it. Basically, I want to have if this and that for compiling. So i want there to be one main.css, and multiple sectionA.css. And when server starts it pre compiles everything to one.css for each section.

This is just one scenario I felt i couldn't make gruntjs do, I can see doing it but it just makes it populated it doesn't seem right way to do it.

Comment: Grunt, or Gulp, is what you need, but you don't have to do all the work yourself. Try one of the yeoman generators http://yeoman.io/generators/

Comment: hi, can you explain what will yeoman do here?

Comment: also i mentioned it before, i felt it was hard to do conditional concats in gruntjs.